Why are quasiconformal maps orientation preserving under the analytic definition?
Quasiconformal maps admit a lot of equivalent definitions.
One of the geometric definitions states that a homeomorphism $f$ is quasiconformal, iff it preserves orientation and changes the modulie of quadrilaterals by a bounded amount. In particular, we have to require that the map $f$ preserves orientation.
Now one of the analytic definitions states, that a homeomorphism $f$ is quasiconformal, iff:

Both partial derivatives $f_z$ and $f_{\bar{z}}$ exist in the distributional sense and belong to $L_{loc}^2$,
There exists some $0 \le \kappa < 1$ such that $|f_{\bar{z}}| \le \kappa |f_z|$ holds in $L_{loc}^2$.

The analytic definition doesn't require the map to be orientation preserving, this should follow from the second point. This is the part I am confused about and would love some insight on.
To simplify the discussion, let's look at the $\mathcal{C}^1$-case, i.e. continuously differentiable quasiconformal maps. Here the Jacobian is well defined and it suffices to show $Jac(f) > 0$. Using the condition $|f_{\bar{z}}| \le \kappa |f_z|$ we get
$$Jac(f) = |f_z|^2 - |f_{\bar{z}}|^2 \ge |f_z|^2(1-\kappa^2) \ge 0,$$
so it suffices to see $f_z \neq 0$.
Let $A$ be the set of points, where $f_z = 0$.
By the condition $|f_{\bar{z}}| \le \kappa |f_z|$ we also have $f_{\bar{z}} = 0$ on $A$.
If the set $A$ has positive measure, it contains some connected open subset and $f$ will need to be constant on this subset, but this contradicts the fact that $f$ is injective. Hence $A$ has measure $0$ and $Jac(f) > 0$ almost everywhere.
That's as far as I've gotten, but I can't seem to finish the proof. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
PS: In particular, does this mean that $\mathcal{C}^1$-quasiconformal maps are automatically $\mathcal{C}^1$-diffemorphisms? This should follow from the inverse function theorem, right?

You have to decide on how you define orientation preserving homeomorphisms: Do you use the topological degree?

@MoisheKohan My question arose while studying the book Lectures on quasiconformal mappings by Ahlfors. There he uses the notion of "sense preserving" which for C^1 maps should be equivalent to the Jacobian being strictly positive. Admittedly, I'm not familiar with the term "sense preserving", but from what I gather from here this shoul just mean that the map preserves the winding number of Jordan curves. The question then becomes, why does sense preserving a.e. imply sense preserving.

The winding number is the same as topological degree. I remember seeing a degree argument using approximation via smooth functions in $W^{1,2}$ in Reshetnyak's book in all dimensions (but there should be also an early reference in dimension 2). I will write an answer later on when I have more time.

Thank you very much, I really apreciate it!

I am sure there are other places where it is proven specifically in dimension 2, but for quasiconformal (even more generally, quasiregular) maps, it is proven in Lemma 6.1 (page 173) in
Reshetnyak, Yu. G., Space mappings with bounded distortion, Translations of Mathematical Monographs, 73. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS). xv, 362 p. {$} 129.00 (1989). ZBL0667.30018.
that if $f: U\to V$ is a quasiconformal mapping of domains in $\mathbb R^n$ and $J_f\ge 0$ almost everywhere, then $f$ is orientation-preserving in the following sense:
For every $x\in U$ and $y=f(x)\in V$, the topological degree, $deg(y, f, U)$ (of $f$ over $y$) equals $+1$.
In dimension 2, it is equivalent to the condition that for a small circle $C$ around $x$, the winding number of $f(C)$ around $y$ is $+1$. Reshetnyak's proof is via an approximation argument: he approximates $f$ in $W^{1,n}_{loc}$ by smooth mappings and notes that one has convergence of integrals of Jacobians of approximating functions $f_i$ to the integral of the Jacobian of $f$. Then he argues for a small ball $B$ around $x$, $\int_B J_f>0$ and, hence, $\int_B J_{f_i}>0$ for all large $i$. From this, he concludes that $deg(y, f_i, U)=1$ and, hence,  by the continuity of the degree, $deg(y, f, U)=1$ as well.
Furthermore, he proves that either $J_f\ge 0$ a.e. in $U$ or $J_f\le 0$ a.e. in $U$.
Sadly, Ahlfors, glosses over this point and do not even discuss the definition of "sense-preserving" (orientation-preserving) homeomorphisms of domains in $\mathbb R^2$. The same problem is in Lehto's book. Hubbard does not do much better either (he mentions positive degree but does not give a proof). I have not checked other sources.
